# Verifying a PSU provides as advertised

Tags: power-supply

I want to ensure I get 3A from a powerbank that claims it is giving 5V/3A output. It is for a project using Raspberry Pi (but this question is not Raspberry Pi specific) and I don't want to damage it.

I've read that I can test a power source by creating a controlled load that draws 3A under 5V.
I can put a few dc motors in series until the sum draws 3A (please suggest better way, as I don't have much equipment except a decent multimeter) and measure the amperes drawn. But if I draw too much from the power bank, I risk to damage it. Is there a safer way to do it?

Comment: a light bulb ...

Comment: You can't really do much without any equipment. Do you at least have a multimeter? If no, then your best bet is to try to find a load with a known resistance or power draw. Motors are not ideal since they're an inductive load and the current spike during startup might damage your powerbank.

Comment: Yes I have a multimeter

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a 1.66 ohm resistor with a power rating of 15W or more then this is preferable to using motors, since their load will be noisy and difficult to control.  Two 3.3 ohm resistors in parallel would be a good approximation and would draw 3.03A provided that the output remains at 5V.  If you’re using two resistors then each one should be rated at 7.5W or better.  You might consider investing a few $ in a multimeter- even the cheapest one is much better than nothing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. I do have a decent multimeter. How can I verify that it is safe for the battery to be drawing 3A? If it doesn't get hot?

Comment: The power bank should have protection for over current. If the spec says 5V 3A then that does not seem unreasonable for a LiIon battery pack that could easily supply well in excess of 3A. Car light bulbs can make a useful load or you can get nichrome wire from an old toaster and make your own calibrated resistor - find the length that gives the current you require but note it may get hot (very likely).

Comment: @Sirode If in doubt, do the experiment outdoors on a fireproof surface.  If the powerbank catches fire, throw a bucket of water over it, then buy a better one.  There's no way to test that the powerbank can deliver 3A without actually drawing 3A from it and seeing what happens.  If it fails, it was no good anyway.